# cloning server to almost identical server

Tags: server, clonezilla, cloning

My hosting company has lowered its prices, but if I want to be on the new fare, I have to create a new server, which sucks.

The new server's hardware will be strictly identical to the current one. Except that now I can choose between SATA or SSD disk. Currently I have SATA but I'm thinking it could be a good thing to opt for SSD, especially since I don't need that much storage.

My question is: can I clone the existing server (e.g:using clonezilla) and restore it on the new server, knowing the only difference would be the SSD disk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically it should work. 
A few things you should be aware of:
If /etc/fstab uses UUID to identify partitions, then you'll probably have to edit it to work with the new SSD. 
You should probably also change the hostname, unless the old server is not going to run anymore.

Seeing as it's the same architecture and pretty much same hardware, you should be able to run the same kernel and the same applications as before.

Comment: ok that's good news. The old server will be trashed.